# Haskell: proving with Typeable that `exists t. a ~ D t`

Tags: haskell, dynamic-typing

I have

```hs
data D t = ...
data SomeStuff = forall a (Typeable a, ...) => SomeStuff a
```

and at some point I get a SomeStuff whose internal `a` I'd like to try and cast to `D t` (where `t` can by *any* type, I'm only interested in the `D` part). Something which (in pseudo-Haskell) would look like:

```hs
case someStuff of
  SomeStuff (_ :: a) -> case eqT :: Maybe (a :~: (exists t. D t)) of
    Just Refl -> -- proven that `exists t. a ~ D t`
    Nothing -> -- nothing to do here
```

I've been fiddling around with `Data.Type.Equality` and `Type.Reflection` (like App etc) and I can't get it to work. Anyone has a way to do that?

Comment: The thing is that `t` can be anything. I can't constrain it on some type like `()`.

Comment: Based on the answer I probably totally got the question wrong - sorry

Answer (score 6):

Testing whether the type is of the form `D _` can be achieved exploiting `Type.Reflection`, as follows.

We start from giving some concrete definitions modeled on your example, so that we can test our code later on.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators, TypeApplications #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

import Type.Reflection

data D t = D1 | D2  -- whatever
data SomeStuff = forall a. (Typeable a, Show a) => SomeStuff a
```

Then, we test for `D _` as follows:

```
foo :: SomeStuff -> (forall t. D t -> String) -> String
foo (SomeStuff (x :: a)) f = case typeRep @a of
   App d _ | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @D) d -> f x
   _ -> "the SomeStuff argument does not contain a value of type D t for any t"
```

Above, we take as arguments both the `SomeStuff` value and a polymorphic function `f`. The latter requires an argument of the form `D _` and is used here only to show that our approach actually works -- you can remove the `f` argument if you don't need that.

After that, we take `takeRep @a` which models the (reflected) type representation of our unknown type `a`. We check whether that matches with the pattern `App d _`, i.e. whether type `a` is an application of `d` to something we don't care `_`. If so, we check whether `d` is indeed the (reflected representation of) our `D` type constructor. Matching the result of `eqTypeRepl` against `Just HRefl` makes GHC assume `a ~ D t` for some fresh type variable `t`, which is what we want. After that, we can call `f x` confirming GHC inferred the wanted type.

As an alternative, we can exploit view patterns to make our code more compact, without sacrificing the readability too much:

```
foo :: SomeStuff -> (forall t. D t -> String) -> String
foo (SomeStuff (x :: a)) f = case typeRep @a of
   App (eqTypeRep (typeRep @D) -> Just HRefl) _ -> f x
   _ -> "the SomeStuff argument does not contain a value of type D t for any t"
```

Comment: Thanks! :) The key was `eqTypeRep` which for some reason I missed...