# Extract a Maybe from a heterogeneous collection

Tags: haskell, types

I have a project where I define a "heterogenous list" like the following. I'm not sure what this trick is called but I've found it to be useful:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

data (a :: Type) :> (b :: Type) = a :> b
  deriving Show
infixr :>
```

With this, I can write arbitrarily long lists of values like this:

```
val :: Int :> Bool :> String
val = 42 :> True :> "asdf"
```

I'm trying to write a function to test if such a value contains a given type, and if so extract it as a `Maybe`. For example,

```hs
-- | getInt (42 :> "asdf") -> Just 42
-- | getInt (True :> "asdf") -> Nothing
getInt :: a :> b -> Maybe Int
getInt _ = ???
```

But I haven't figured out a way to write functions like this. I tried using
`cast` from `Data.Typeable`, but ran into various problems trying to destructure at the type level.

Comment: I think this is relevant: [proving with Typeable that `exists t. a ~ D t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105950/haskell-proving-with-typeable-that-exists-t-a-d-t). Note however that your `a :> b` type is essentially the same as `(a,b)`.

Comment: What you want is going to be difficult. I'd recommend using an existing library instead; [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) is the obvious choice. But _generally_, checking something like "does it match this type or not" is quite unidiomatic. Why can't you have a dedicated data type that expresses this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do this with `Type.Reflection`, as per @chi's comment (see below).

However, you might find it easier to use a more traditional list type with both a "cons" and a "nil" constructor and embedded `Typeable` instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

infixr 5 :>
data HList ts where
  (:>) :: (Typeable t) => t -> HList ts -> HList (t ': ts)
  Nil :: HList '[]
```

Note that you can maintain most of the ergonomics of the original with a few cleverly named type families and aliases:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

type family (:>) t ts where
  t :> HList ts = HList (t ': ts)
  t :> x = TypeError (Text "(:>) type ended with " :<>: ShowType x
                     :<>: Text " instead of Nil")
type Nil = HList '[]
```

This allows you to write:

```
val :: Int :> Bool :> String :> Nil
val = 42 :> True :> "asdf" :> Nil
```

because the `:>` and `Nil` in types are type families/aliases which expand to a valid `HList` type, and the `:>` and `Nil` in expressions are the constructors for the corresponding `HList` type.

With this in place, it's easy to define `getInt` with just `cast` from `Data.Typeable`:

```
import Data.Typeable

getInt :: HList ts -> Maybe Int
getInt (x :> xs) | Just a <- cast x = Just a
                 | otherwise = getInt xs
getInt Nil = Nothing
```

Critically, the extra `Nil` constructor eliminates the need to try to distinguish at the type level if the right-hand side of a `:>` constructor is a final value or "more list".

This will generally be much more pleasant to work with in all sorts of ways at the relatively small cost of a little `:> Nil` boilerplate.

A full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module KindList2 where

import Data.Typeable
import GHC.TypeError

infixr :>
type family (:>) t ts where
  t :> HList ts = HList (t ': ts)
  t :> x = TypeError (Text "(:>) type ended with " :<>: ShowType x
                     :<>: Text " instead of Nil")
type Nil = HList '[]

data HList ts where
  (:>) :: Typeable t => t -> HList ts -> HList (t ': ts)
  Nil :: HList '[]

getInt :: HList ts -> Maybe Int
getInt (x :> xs) | Just a <- cast x = Just a
                 | otherwise = getInt xs
getInt Nil = Nothing

v1 :: Int :> Bool :> String :> Nil
v1 = 42 :> True :> "asdf" :> Nil
v2 :: String :> Int :> String :> Nil
v2 = "between" :> 2 :> "strings" :> Nil
v3 :: String :> Int :> Nil
v3 = "sweet" :> 16 :> Nil
v4 :: String :> Bool :> Nil
v4 = "contains Int = " :> False :> Nil

main = do
  print $ getInt v1
  print $ getInt v2
  print $ getInt v3
  print $ getInt v4
```

which produces the output:

```
λ> main
Just 42
Just 2
Just 16
Nothing
```

However, if you want to stick with your `:>`-only approach, then `Data.Typeable` is insufficient because it can't be "decomposed" at the type level.  You've probably observed that it's easy enough to write:

```
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Typeable

data (a :: Type) :> (b :: Type) = a :> b
  deriving (Show)
infixr :>

getInt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a :> b -> Maybe Int
getInt (a :> b) | Just x <- cast a = Just x
                | Just x <- cast b = Just x
```

which can successfully extract the `Int` from `Int :> Bool` and `Bool :> Int`, but there's no straightforward way to recurse using `cast`:

```
getInt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a :> b -> Maybe Int
getInt (a :> b) | Just x <- cast a = Just x
                | Just x <- cast b = Just x
                | Just rest <- cast b = getInt rest   -- ERROR
```

Because even though the `cast b` can successfully cast `b` to a `c :> d`, there's no way to get the required `Typeable c` and `Typeable d` constraints from `Typeable b`.

However, if you use `Type.Reflection` instead, it's possible.  Note that I've used explicit export lists here, but basically I've used `cast` from `Data.Typeable` for convenience, and everything else (including the `Typeable` type itself) needs to come from `Type.Reflection).

```
import Data.Typeable (cast)
import Type.Reflection (Typeable, pattern App, pattern HRefl, pattern TypeRep,
                        typeOf, eqTypeRep, withTypeable,)


getInt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a :> b -> Maybe Int
getInt (a :> b)

  -- handle `Int :> a`
  | Just x <- cast a = Just x

  -- handle `x :> (y :> z)`
  --   extract type (of right-hand side) as:  c `op` d
  | App (App op c) d <- typeOf b
  --   check op ~ (:>)
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep op (TypeRep @(:>))
  --   extract Typeable c, Typeable d, and recurse
    = withTypeable c $ withTypeable d $ getInt b

  -- handle `x :> Int`
  | Just x <- cast b = Just x

  -- handle remaining cases
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

The full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}            -- needed to avoid "fragile" guard bindings
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}  -- only needed for import list
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module KindList where

import Data.Typeable (cast)
import Type.Reflection (Typeable, pattern App, pattern HRefl, pattern TypeRep,
                        typeOf, eqTypeRep, withTypeable,)

data a :> b = a :> b deriving (Show)
infixr :>

getInt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a :> b -> Maybe Int
getInt (a :> b)
  | Just x <- cast a = Just x
  | App (App op c) d <- typeOf b
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep op (TypeRep @(:>))
    = withTypeable c $ withTypeable d $ getInt b
  | Just x <- cast b = Just x
  | otherwise = Nothing

v1 :: Int :> Bool :> String
v1 = 42 :> True :> "asdf"
v2 :: String :> Int :> String
v2 = "between" :> 2 :> "strings"
v3 :: String :> Int
v3 = "sweet" :> 16
v4 :: String :> Bool
v4 = "contains Int = " :> False

main = do
  print $ getInt v1
  print $ getInt v2
  print $ getInt v3
  print $ getInt v4
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can do something like this. I use the standard `(,)` instead of your `(:>)`, but only to keep the code minimal; there's nothing fundamental that can't be ported to your type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Type.Reflection

get :: forall needle haystack. (Typeable needle, Typeable haystack) =>
    haystack -> Maybe needle
get haystack = case typeOf haystack of
    (eqTypeRep (typeRep @needle) -> Just HRefl)
        -> Just haystack
    App (App (eqTypeRep (typeRep @(,)) -> Just HRefl) a) b
        ->  withTypeable a (get (fst haystack))
        <|> withTypeable b (get (snd haystack))
    _ -> Nothing
```

Try it in ghci:

```
> get @Integer (42, (True, "asdf"))
Just 42
> get @Integer (True, (42, "asdf"))
Just 42
> get @Integer (True, ("asdf", 42))
Just 42
> get @Integer (True, ('w', "asdf"))
Nothing
```

Actually, this recurses on both sides of  the tuple, so it works for some things you might not have imagined; e.g. `get @Integer (("asdf", 42), True)` also returns `Just 42`. This can be prevented if desired; simply perform another typerep equality check in the first argument to `<|>` instead of recursing.

This uses `withTypeable`, but then immediately pattern matches on the associated `typeRep`. If science goes too far and you find you care about the performance of this abomination, you can avoid that, making O(1) calls to `typeRep`, like this.

```
get :: forall needle haystack. (Typeable needle, Typeable haystack) =>
    haystack -> Maybe needle
get = go typeRep where
    go :: forall haystack. TypeRep haystack -> haystack -> Maybe needle
    go (eqTypeRep needleTy -> Just HRefl) needle = Just needle
    go (App (App (eqTypeRep pairTy -> Just HRefl) aTy) bTy) (a, b)
        = go aTy a <|> go bTy b
    go _ _ = Nothing

    needleTy :: TypeRep needle
    needleTy = typeRep

    pairTy :: TypeRep (,)
    pairTy = typeRep
```